# Как узнать кто отправил письмо мне на почту (емайл)?

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap

Нужно создать функцию, которая будет заходить на Google Mail и выдавать мне почту с которой пришло мне письма. Не могу решить эту проблему, много чего пытался, ничего не помогало.

Как это можно сделать?

```
import imaplib

login = str(self.login.get())
        password = str(self.password.get())
        mail1 = str(self.mail.get())
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
        mail.login({login},{password})
        mail.select('inbox')
```

Тут я использую блоки ввода информации, и в этой функции использую их.

Comment: Есть более простое решение - заходить по imap.

Comment: Я делаю через эту библиотеку, но я именно не могу найти как это сделать в плане когда. Т.е. я написал код которых заходит на почту там все норм. А что бы вывести кто прислал мне письмо я не могу(найти).

Comment: может быть, если Вы добавите подробностей - например, про конкретную библиотеку - то найдутся знатоки, которые подскажут в этой библиотеке метод, возвращаюший список писем и набор атрибутов для конкретного письма

Comment: Вот да, только начал это делать)

Comment: похоже, Вам просто нужно немного продвинуться вперед в использовании библиотеки - кажется, в ней есть все нужные для решения задачи методы. Можно погуглить по python imaplib example

Comment: Я уже смотрел там, а так, спасибо за ваши ответы)

Comment: что значит `"выдавать мне почту с которой пришло мне письма"`? Речь о поиске по какому-то из критериев или о чем-то другом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
import re
import imaplib
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('mymail@gmail.com','mypassword')

# сначала выбираем папку All Mail
folder = [re.sub(r'.*?("\[G[^"]*").*', r'\1', f.decode("utf-8"))  for f in mail.list()[1] if br"\All " in f][0]

mail.select(folder)

# поиск писем по отправителю
typ, data = mail.search(None, '(FROM "Paul")')
```

ID найденных писем

```
In [29]: data
Out[29]: [b'5828 6791 6956 7523 7840']
```

читаем и парсим одно из найденных писем:

```
typ, d = mail.fetch('5828', '(RFC822)')
msg = email.message_from_bytes(d[0][1])
```

аттрибуты `msg`:

```
In [34]: msg.keys()
Out[34]:
['Delivered-To',
 'Received',
 'X-Received',
 'Return-Path',
 'Received',
 'Received-SPF',
 'Authentication-Results',
 'Received',
 'DKIM-Signature',
 'X-Google-DKIM-Signature',
 'X-Gm-Message-State',
 'X-Received',
 'MIME-Version',
 'Received',
 'Received',
 'From',
 'Date',
 'Message-ID',
 'Subject',
 'To',
 'Content-Type']
```

дальше можно посмотреть каждый из этих атрибутов:

```
In [35]: print(msg["from"])
Paul ****** <paul.******@******.com>
```

Comment: У меня decode подчеркивает, с ем это может быть связанно?

Comment: Забыл вас поблагодарить, спасибо большое это дало мне сильный продвиг в моем понимании и в разработке программы.

Comment: Все, сделал, как насчет decode? У меня ответ приходит в частично зашифрованном виде -(Cannot find reference 'decode' in 'None' )

Comment: @Karlson12, какая у васверсия Python?

Comment: У меня версия 3,8,5

Comment: @Karlson12, не получается воспроизвести проблему с `decode`...